# Matching a surge function to dataset

Tags: fitting

I am trying to generate a surge function form of best fit to a dataset using the code from the appendix of https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/10511970608984137.

```
data = {{ .05 , 5}, { .3 , 60}, { 0.5 , 330 }, {1 , 450 }, {1.4, 420}, {2 , 355}, {3, 250}, {4 , 180}, {6 , 80} ,{8,50}, {10, 30}, {12, 20}, {18, 10}, {24 , 8}}
m[x_, a_,b_] = a x Exp [-b x] 
ss[a_,b_] = Sum [(data[[l, 2]] - m[data[[l , 1]], a, b])^2, {l, 1 , Length[data]} ] 
sm = FindMinimum[ss[a , b] , {a, 1}, {b , 1}]
mf [x_] = m[x, a,b] /. FindMinimum[ss[a ,b] ,{ a, 1},{b , 1} ] [[2]]
```

I'm very new to using Mathematica and have no idea what's wrong with it.

Thank you.

Comment: There are two issues:  (1) there are some copy-and-paste errors such as `Lengt h` and `dat a` and `/ .FindMinimum` (which should be `/. FindMinimum`. and (2) all of the `=` should be `:=` except for `sm = FindMinimum`.

Answer (score 5):

Your code with a few corrections:

```
data = {{.05, 5}, {.3, 60}, {0.5, 330}, {1, 450}, {1.4, 420}, {2, 355}, 
  {3, 250}, {4, 180}, {6, 80}, {8, 50}, {10, 30}, {12, 20}, {18, 10}, {24, 8}};
m[x_, a_, b_] := a x Exp[-b x]
ss[a_, b_] := Sum[(data[[l, 2]] - m[data[[l, 1]], a, b])^2, {l, 1, Length[data]}]
sm = FindMinimum[ss[a, b], {a, 1}, {b, 1}]
(* {28832.3, {a -> 799.054, b -> 0.718672}} *)
mf[x_] := m[x, a, b] /. FindMinimum[ss[a, b], {a, 1}, {b, 1}][[2]]
```

And it's not a great fit:

```
Show[ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[m[x, a, b] /. sm[[2]], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

It would probably be better if you used `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, m[x, a, b], {a, b}, x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 799.054, b -> 0.718672} *)
Show[ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[nlm[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

which will get the same results.

Comment: This seems to work perfect. While it's not the greatest fit, the investigation says to discuss the suitability of surge functions on a dataset, which is why I wanted to compare the resulting surge functions using calculus and technology. Thank you again for your assistance.